# How to I get folder outside of my Laravel (v9) project or Is there's a way to do that?

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

Let say. I have this project folder that shows like this in the server.

`var/www/html/my_project`

then I want to access this folder name (my_folder) outside of my_project folder

`var/www/html/my_folder`

The reason that I want to get that folder, Because it contains a large amount of data. Which is I don't want to put those data inside of my public/storage folder.

I hope someone can help me about this part or some idea where I can apply it in my project.

I'm trying to use storage like this in my code.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$check_storage = Storage::disk('my_folder');
```

then in my filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

        'my_folder' => 
        [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>'/var/www/html/my_folder',
        ],
]
```

but still not working in my end.

Comment: What part of it isn't working? What error message is it giving, if any?

Comment: Why do you want to put it into your public folder, you can simply generate a storage folder and link this one, then the data would be in your project and easy accessible for your controllers but not for the public. 
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408201/accessing-files-from-a-folder-outside-the-root-folder-laravel it is pretty much the same question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing files from a folder outside the root folder laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408201/accessing-files-from-a-folder-outside-the-root-folder-laravel)

Comment: Just us a symlink.... pure Linux...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got an answer. Just did what I want.
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

```
$storage = Storage::disk('storage')
           ->getDriver()
           ->getAdapter()
           ->getPathPrefix();

$files = glob($storage.'*');

foreach($files as $folder)
{
     dd(glob($folder.'/*'));
} 
I hope this will help also to everyone.
```